# How to interpret SD card speeds?

Tags: sd-card

I'm buying a gift for my friend and I know that he needs a fast SD card. I did a bit of research and it looks like UHS3 is the fastest currently available option, but I have a couple of questions related to card speed:

- Does UHS3 mean the same thing in SD/MicroSD context?
- Does UHS3 strictly define the speed one can expect from an SD card, or is there anything else one should take into account?
- I heard that UHS3 has extra pins for the extra transfer and if one has an UHS3 MicroSD card, a special adapter is required to take advantage of its speed, otherwise it will be running at regular 10 speed. Is that correct?
- Is there anything else one has to take into account when buying an SD/MicroSD card that I want to be as fast as possible?

I was thinking of buying this one:

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=fa&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fallegro.pl%2Foferta%2Fsandisk-32-gb-micro-sd-sdhc-uhs3-extreme-100-60mbs-7473293859

Apologies for the sloppy translation, there's no English version; the last picture shows the actual product I'm considering.